# Read a file and convert all letters to uppercase

Tags: python, string

I created a .txt file with random words that I'm importing into my script. I want then to take all the words, print one on each line and convert them all to uppercase. I have the first part done:

```
a=open("redchief.txt").read().split()

print ' \n'.join(a)
```

I'm having problems converting the data into capital letters. Here is some of the data:

```
It looked like a good thing: but wait till I tell you.
```

Comment: I know how to do it if I did s = asdf then did s.upper() but I'm having problem since I'm reading in a file. Maybe I'm making it too complicated. I read that post before I posted. I didn't want to make a duplicate.

Comment: You've gotten pretty far on your own; that's good! Your problem statement is very vague, though. If you've read that post and tried something, please edit your question to be more specific about what the trouble is and what you're not understanding.

Comment: Why is it a problem if you read in a file?

Comment: It looks like `"It looked like a good thing: but wait till I tell you."` is the sentence from your file, right? So you are not using a random words in terms of CS random. If so, you are NOT calling upper() as @JoshCaswell wrote...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your last line from:

```
print ' \n'.join(a)
```

to:

```
print ' \n'.join(a).upper()
```

you don't have to store the result in a separate variable first, since `' \n'.join(a)` gives you a string object whose `upper()` method you can call.